# SSRS 2005 giving me "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined" when trying to customize it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm getting the error "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined" when customizing it.  I've made several changes to the configuration files and UI, but I keep getting this error.  It isn't logging it too in the event log nor the log files, which makes it very annoying to debug.  So how do I figure out where the error is coming from?  Is it with the URL that's pointing to the ReportServer2005.asmx file, or something else?

Updated: The specific error being logged is:

> aspnet_wp!library!9!3/11/2010-15:52:49::
>   i INFO: Initializing
>   WatsonDumpOnExceptions to default
>   value of
>   'Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException,Microsoft.ReportingServices.Modeling.InternalModelingException'
>   because it was not specified in
>   Configuration file.
>   aspnet_wp!library!9!3/11/2010-15:52:49::
>   i INFO: Initializing
>   WatsonDumpExcludeIfContainsExceptions
>   to default value of
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,System.Threading.ThreadAbortException'
>   because it was not specified in
>   Configuration file.
>   aspnet_wp!library!9!3/11/2010-15:52:49::
>   i INFO: Initializing
>   SecureConnectionLevel to default value
>   of '1'  because it was not specified
>   in Configuration file.
>   aspnet_wp!library!9!3/11/2010-15:52:49::
>   i INFO: Initializing DisplayErrorLink
>   to 'True'  as specified in
>   Configuration file.
>   aspnet_wp!library!9!3/11/2010-15:52:49::
>   i INFO: Initializing
>   WebServiceUseFileShareStorage to
>   default value of 'False'  because it
>   was not specified in Configuration
>   file.
>   aspnet_wp!ui!9!3/11/2010-15:52:52:: e
>   ERROR: Invalid URI: The format of the
>   URI could not be determined.
>   aspnet_wp!ui!9!3/11/2010-15:52:53:: e
>   ERROR: HTTP status code --> 500
>   -------Details-------- System.UriFormatException: Invalid
>   URI: The format of the URI could not
>   be determined.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.RSConnection.GetSecureMethods()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Global.RSWebServiceWrapper.GetSecureMethods()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.RSConnection.IsSecureMethod(String methodname)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.RSConnection.ValidateConnection()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Global.SecureAllAPI()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.EnsureHttpsLevel(HttpsLevel
>   level)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ReportingPage_Init(Object
>   sender, EventArgs args)
>
> at
>   System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>
> at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs
>   e)
>
> at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)
>
> at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control
>   namingContainer)
>
> at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   aspnet_wp!ui!9!3/11/2010-15:52:53:: e
>   ERROR: Exception in ShowErrorPage:
>   System.Threading.ThreadAbortException:
>   Thread was being aborted.    at
>   System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
>   at
>   System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object
>   stateInfo)    at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.End()    at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String
>   path, Boolean preserveForm)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ShowErrorPage(String
>   errMsg) at    at
>   System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
>   at
>   System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object
>   stateInfo)    at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.End()    at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String
>   path, Boolean preserveForm)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ShowErrorPage(String
>   errMsg)

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give a few more details about what you've changed on the configuration file and where you are receiving this message? Is it when trying to access Report Manager in your browser?

If you clear out the log files in the SSRS directory (mine is in Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFile in SQL Server 2008 - 2005 should be similar) and restart, what are the items logged before you hit an error?

Comment: I updated the post; it finally logged the error.  I changed the config to point to my local DB (this is my local RS server BTW).  The config changes were to use forms auth, following a setup my co-worker has recently deployed successfully.  I'm trying to duplicate it; this error is something he didn't experience.

Comment: From the message it's pretty certainly a config issue rather than a network issue, but I haven't come across that exact message before.

Do you know what config file changes were made from a base install? Specifically, is there anything different in the <URLReservations> or <Authentication> sections of the config file (again, assuming the same config layout for 2005 and 2008)?

Comment: I'm deploying a custom authentication/authorization extension, so yes.  Don't have the project handy, but <Authentication> did change.

Comment: Ugh, sorry, I can't help on this one, but am interested in the solution. I started on a custom security extension a while back unless we discovered we didn't need it - I was successful when I used minimal security but when I set things up "properly" I had all kinds of problems.

For what it's worth, 'Applied Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services' by Teo Lachiev has a good chapter on security extensions. You could download the book source code from http://prologika.com/CS/media/p/3617.aspx and see if you have an 'aha' moment.